# Entering search pattern with syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, command-line, regular-expression

A search pattern used with `/`, entered on the vim command line,
can be very complex.

But even for a normal regular expression pattern, syntax highlight of the expression syntax would be helpful.

The pattern syntax in `vim` provides a large number of special pattern atoms. Some of them use multiple characters.
I do need to look them up to use them - that's easy.
The harder part is to continue editing the pattern, because it can become hard to read quickly.

I think even a very simple kind of syntax highlight for the pattern input would be helpful, like three colors for text, standard pattern atoms and special pattern atoms.

It would help users new to writing nontrivial patterns a lot - and also, it would help experienced users, new to writing even more advanced patterns, just the same way.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is here. Do you want general highlight of the search string? Or highlighting as you type? Do you want to change the color of the highlighting based on the type of search string?

Comment: Some basic highlighting is available in the search window (invoked by `q/`). It's not extensive, but perhaps a syntax plugin could improve it.

Comment: I guess I was thinking about the command window (`q:`). It uses VimScript highlighting.

Comment: @Bernhard Yes, it should be highlighting as you type, ideally.  Thanks to point it out. Basically, I want to make the syntax of the pattern after `/` visible. Literal text should be a fixed color (a code fragment in the pattern is not highlighted).

Answer (score 4):

There's no highlighting in the *command-line*; that's not implemented.

What you can do is open the *command-line window* via `q/`, and `:set syntax=...` there (also automatically via `:autocmd CmdwinEnter / setlocal syntax=...`). Unfortunately, even the syntax for Vimscript doesn't provide any differentiation in `/.../` patterns. So, you'd have to write such syntax (e.g. named `vimregexp`) yourself. A worthwhile challenge, and such plugin would probably be well received by the Vim community (and could even be included in / be an extension of the `syntax/vim.vim` plugin).

Comment: I think the [VimRegEx.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1091) plugin perhaps does this? I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly check if your regexp search pattern works by using [IncSearch.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) plugin. It incrementally highlights ALL pattern matches as you type it.

Comment: It might be useful, but I think this post is more suited to a comment, since it doesn't even come close to answering the question.

Comment: @muru Somehow it's approaching the same problem from a different side: We can not visualize the structure of the pattern in real time; Ok, but instead we visualize what the pattern does in real time. I take it as at least related enough to be an answer - and it may turn out to be pretty useful.